# Google Actions sdk - Unable to persist app.data beyond Q/A sessions

Tags: javascript, actions-on-google

I have a simple game where I am passing values between Q/A sessions between the user and GA. However, I have noticed that the app.state is not maintaining values to the next session.

It's basically asking True/False type questions and passing those to check and validate for those.

Sample Code

```
exports.myQNAFunction = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 // get an instance of the Google Actions SDK
const app = new ActionsSdkApp({request: request, response: response});
app.data = {answer: ''}

// Function to handle the built in intents
function handleBuiltInIntent (app) {

    // Get dialog state to know where we are in the conversation
    var dialogState = app.getDialogState();

    // get our custom parameter
    var stage = dialogState.stage;
    console.info('handleBuiltInIntent: ' + stage);
    console.info('app.data.answer: ' + app.data.answer);

    // Check where we are in the conversation
    if(stage === 1) {
        console.info("block stage 1 ")
        let rawInput = app.getRawInput();
        if(rawInput === 'ok' || rawInput === 'yes' || rawInput === 'sure') {
            // user wants to know more
            app.tell('Ok then, here are the instructions!');
        } else if(rawInput === 'no') {
            dialogState.stage = 2;
            let question = getNextQuestion();
            let answer = qna_object_dict[question];
            app.data.answer = answer
            app.ask(question, dialogState);
        } else {
            // we finish the dialog
            app.tell('Ok then, goodbye!');
        }
    } else if(stage === 2) {
        console.info("block stage 2 ")
        let rawInput = app.getRawInput();
        if (rawInput === app.data.answer) {
            console.info(app.data.answer)
            dialogState.stage = 2;
            let question = getNextQuestion();
            let answer = qna_object_dict[question];
            app.data.answer = answer
            app.ask(question, dialogState);
        } else {
            app.tell('Wong Answer, goodbye!');
        }
    } else {
        // Build a prompt
        console.info("block stage 0 ")
        let welcome_string = welcomePrompt()
        let inputPrompt = app.buildInputPrompt(false,
            welcome_string);
        dialogState.stage = 1;
        app.ask(inputPrompt, dialogState);
    }
}

});
```

Answer (score 2):

[`app.data`](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/AssistantApp#data) is meant to be session-specific data, to maintain state between different steps of a single conversation.

If you want data to persist for a given user between sessions/conversations, you can use the [`app.userStorage`](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/AssistantApp#userStorage).

Comment: I do understand the difference between the two. I am having difficulty storing the app.data values.

However this is what I am doing now:

var dialogState = app.getDialogState()
var stage = dialogState.stage;
var game_score = dialogState.game_score

Comment: If you have changes to the question - update the question instead of trying to say something in the comments. It makes it very difficult to understand what the problem is.

Comment: Instead of using `app.data.answer = answer`, for example, use `app.userStorage.answer = answer`. That will persist data between sessions.